# Is print in TikZ's math, useless?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

In the manual of TikZ 3.0.0, the section about the `math` library, we can read (p. 635):

> Unlike the print keyword, the brace notation can be used in functions so that tikz path commands can be safely executed inside a tikzpicture.

And then there's this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
  \tikzmath{
    coordinate \c;
    for \x in {0,10,...,360}{
      \c = (1.5cm, 1cm) + (\x:1cm and 0.5cm);
      { \fill (\c) circle [radius=1pt]; };
    };
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I replace

```
{ \fill (\c) circle [radius=1pt]; };
```

by

```
print { \fill (\c) circle [radius=1pt]; };
```

I obtain exactly the same result:

[image: output1]

This is probably because there is no function use. If we check with `print` inside a function that is inside a `tikzpicture`, we can see the difference.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] grid (5,2);
    \tikzmath{
      function drawpoint(\s,\t){
        { \fill[red] (\s pt,\t pt) circle [radius=1pt] node[above]{(\s,\t)}; };
        print { \fill[blue] (\s pt,\t pt) circle [radius=1pt] node[below]{(\s,\t)}; };
      };
      coordinate \c; \c = (2cm, 1cm);
      drawpoint(\c);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

So my question is: **Why do we need `print` ?** Is there some example where we must put it?

Comment: There is no difference between `{ ... }` and `print { ... }`. Quoting the TikZ manual "[print] is intended as convenience keyword…"

Comment: @HenriMenke you can see in the example that there is a difference, and you can read the citation that I put from the manual.

Comment: I notice that removing some spaces, as in `...print{\fill...` changes the output.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes interesting. After your comment I checked by putting some text before `\fill` : the `print` displays it (I don't know how, it is not a node), and the `{ }` ignores it. The same for `print {some text};` and `{some text};` inside the function. Both are the same outside the `tikzpicture` (reproducing the text) and between the function and the `tikzpicture` both produce error.

Comment: The difference is that "useless" `print` command does not execute `\nullfont` inside a `tikzpicture` prior to executing its argument (or perform any checks to see if it necessary) making it marginally quicker. Code inside functions is executed by the math parser which installs the prevailing font so that lengths such as `1ex` and `2em` can be evaluation. Thus, `print` should not be used inside functions unless extreme care is taken with spaces as they will be printed. The alternative `{ };` syntax can be used instead.

Comment: @MarkWibrow thanks for the explanation! This looks like an answer to me. So if I understand well, the reason for the existance of print is the speed (like all "q" versions in PGF). Are there any other reasons to use it in some places ?

Comment: @MarkWibrow Could you please transform your comment in answer and I'll accept it. I think this can be useful for other people. This explains for example why `{1};` do nothing and `print{1};`, `{$1$};` and `print{$1$};` result in `1` and `$1$` in the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different between the  `print {some code or text};` and the `{some code or text};` syntax is that the `print` keyword does not execute `\nullfont` inside a `tikzpicture` prior to executing its argument (or perform any checks to see if it necessary) making it marginally quicker.

Code inside functions is executed by the math parser which installs the prevailing font so that lengths such as `1ex` and `2em` can be evaluated. Thus, `print` should not be used inside functions unless extreme care is taken with spaces as they will be printed. The alternative { }; syntax can be used instead.

Additionally `print` is a kind of "syntactic sugar" to make code more readable.

Comment: Thanks to transforming your comment in an answer! In conclusion if I understand well : we should use `{ };` when we "print" inside `tikzpicture` (for example `{\draw circle(1);};`) and we should use `print { };` to "print" outside of `tikzpicture`, for example inside `node`'s text. So `print` is really useful ;)