# Bug in TikZ's math and calc with PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX : workaround?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex

We can use `calc` library inside `tikzmath` to do calculations with coordinates.

Everything works fine if we want to calculate something like `\p3=(0,0)!.5!(2,0);` (inside and outside functions). But if we want a rotation like this `\p3=(0,0)!.5!90:(2,0);` the following happens :

- If we use this kind of calculation in a function and we compile with PDFLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX, all the coordinates are misplaced after that.
- If we do the same calculations outside of function or if we compile with XeLaTex, everything is ok.

Here is a test code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt,convert={density=3500}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \tikzmath{
      % function supposed to draw (0,0) -- (0,1) in red
      function test(\n){ % useless \n parameter
        coordinate \p;
        \p1 = (0,0); \p2 = (2,0);
        \p3 = (\p1)!.5!90:(\p2);
        {\draw[red,thick] (\p1) -- (\p3);};
      };
      % same code outside function : draw (0,0) -- (0,1) in green
      coordinate \p;
      \p1 = (0,0); \p2 = (2,0);
      \p3 = (\p1)!.5!90:(\p2);
      {\draw[green,ultra thick] (\p1) -- (\p3);};
      test(1);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the (bad) result compiled with PDFLaTeX (same as LuaLaTeX):

[image]

Here is the (good) result compiled with XeLaTeX:

[image]

The question is : **Can we work around this bug?**

Some remarks :

- The behaviour is very similar to what we can observe [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219738/9335). And following the [Mark Wibrow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222859/9335), we can suspect a "non `nullfont` problem". That can happens for example if `:` is active character producing some output.
- If we call `test(1)` just after its definition, both lines are misplaced.
- I had to put in `test` function one useless parameter `\n` because we can't have functions without parameter in `tikzmath`. This is, for me, a strange behaviour.

Comment: I checked the number of `<blank space>` and `\nullfont` strings in the log file (with `\tracingcommands=1`) and it's exactly the same either with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: @ereg thanks for checking this! So any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Driver problem, I'd say. Are you sure the syntax is officially supported?

Comment: @egreg as far as I know there is no exactly such example in the manual. But the manual says that we can use `calc` inside `tikzmath` and the syntax is valid `calc` calculation. And it works as expected in some cases.

Comment: The documentation claims the last executed statement in a `function` should be `return`. Is that mistaken?

Comment: @cfr the `return` is not mandatory. If you use it, it must be the last executed statement. One reason is that `return` dont stop the function execution (like in "usual" languages). All statements after the return will be executed too.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is not very clear about that. (I've never used this library, and was just trying to figure it out from the manual and your example.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug in this case is the `calc` library where a line in the definition of `\tikz@cc@scan@rot` is missing a `%` character at the end which affects the parsing of angles in coordinate calculations, for example, parsing `90:(0,1)` in `(0,0)!.5!90:(0,1)`. I don't know why this didn't affect `xelatex` though.

The corrected definition should read as follows:

```
\def\tikz@cc@scan@rot#1{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar({%)
    \tikz@scan@one@point#1% normal
  }%
  {% <- this was missing
    \def\tikz@cc@scan@rot@cmd{#1}%
    \ifnum\the\catcode`\:=\active\relax%
      \expandafter\tikz@cc@scan@one@rot@active%
    \else%
      \expandafter\tikz@cc@scan@one@rot@nonactive%
    \fi%
  }%
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is now [Ticket 483](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/483/) in TikZ's bug tracker. [It might take a while](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427890/is-pgf-tikz-still-actively-developed/428670) before the developers get around to dealing with it.

Comment: And now the bug is fixed (in the source repository). I don't know how long it takes for the fix to migrate onto CTAN and TeX Live.