# Is PGF TIKZ still actively developed?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Indeed, on source forge, it is distributed with CVS and it is indicated this :

> SourceForge only supports read-only access to CVS now. For more
>   information see our blog post about decommissioning CVS commit
>   support. If you are a project admin, you can convert your repository
>   to SVN or Git with these instructions.
>
> [CVS Repository: Code](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/code/)

Moreover, almost no improvement has had an owner since the end of 2016: [Feature Requests](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/), and no updates have been sent to CTAN since 2015.

So, what is the future of `pgf`/TikZ?

Comment: The time passed between version 2.10 and 3.0 is about 3 years. Hence no. Is sourceforge dead? Kinda yes.

Comment: The authors don't need to push to the public repository to keep a project alive. You are just extrapolating.

Comment: My biggest concern about TikZ/PGF is not that it is unmaintained but it lives on SourceForge which is something many projects left due to their horrific practices such as taking over projects from their owners and bootstrapping malware to the installers. I really really hope that they stop using sourceforge and get to where everybody else lives which is GitHub.

Comment: @percusse here is a [question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6300/9335) and here is a [ticket](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/72/) about Git(Hub). I hope that mooving to Git[Hub/Lab/...] will allow faster bug correction, even if the release cycle is not shorter.

Comment: @Kpym Yes but so far nothing happened. It's been years

Comment: @percusse maybe millions of billions of votes and argued comments on [this ticket](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/72/) will change something ... we are almost there ;)

Comment: PGF/Tikz is now under [git](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/72/#7094), it can be cloned by `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/pgf/git`, so moving a copy to GitHub (or linking a GitHub repo with the SF) should be very easy now. Things are moving ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Following direct discussion with the team behind `pgf`]

The `pgf`/TikZ developers are still active and are mindful of the need to convert from CVS to (probably) Git.  The full details and timing will depend on the commitments of the developers concerned. At present, it seems likely that the code will remain hosted on SourceForge.

---

The conversion has now happened: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/master/tree/

Comment: Many thanks to you and the pgf/tikz team.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77732/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-is-pgf-tikz-still-actively-developed).

Comment: Since April 2018, there have been updates on sourceforge but not on CTAN, do you know the TikZ team's intentions on this subject?

Comment: @AndréC No, but that's entirely up to them: software releases are down to developers, not to 'community' feeling