# Is pgf/TiKZ "feature complete"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The last version of TiKZ was 3.0.1, released on 2015-08-29. From what I understand from the code repository [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/master/tree/), development is not active at all. I understand this to be a great thing and to mean that there are just very few bugs, and that it is basically feature complete. Is this correct?

Or has development basically moved to "sub-packages" that are not in the core package. If so, what are the main packages and where is their source code so I can follow the development?

It is fascinating to me that TiKZ is so popular, but that its development seems not very active the past years. I take this to be a good signal that it is extremely stable and not many improvements are needed.

Comment: This has been asked before. They are not on source forge anymore. I think they are in github like most other projects

Comment: Funny there was a very similar question a few days/weeks ago that came to the opposite conclusion, that it is a very negative sign...

Comment: @daleif No, they’re on SF. But they changed from CVS to Git.

Comment: The above mentioned question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427890/586