# What's new in the latest version 3.1 of TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

TikZ version 3.1 is [available on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) since January 5, 2019.

Christian Feuersaenger published the latest version [on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/3.1/tree/) on the same day.

The manual of version 3.0.1a which had 1161 pages now has 1282 pages.

#### What's new in this version?

Comment: Do not get me wrong, but I am not sure this question is suitable for the website... The answer is simply a link to either an announcement or release notes...

Comment: There will be others that will be more detailed.

Comment: @PauloCereda are you sure the correct answer isn't "121 pages" ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's advanced math, of course. `:)`

Comment: Are there any speed improvements?

Comment: @PauloCereda When I asked this question on meta: [Is PGF TIKZ still actively developed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427890/138900), it was moved here. So....

Comment: Meta is for question about TeX Stack Exchange managing. This is not a question for Meta, it's only perhaps off topic

Comment: Read the changelog: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/ChangeLog . I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for off-site resources.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't understand what off-site resources means.

Comment: @AndréC If you're asking *where to find* something, it means that it can't be found on this site which makes it an off-site resource (most common examples are asking for a font, tool, or book).  You are asking what the changes in PGF 3.1 are, which basically means that you are asking *where to find* the changes (even though you didn't phrase it exactly like that).

Comment: @HenriMenke The same question is not closed on version 3.0 [What are the new features in TikZ/pgf 3.0?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153392/138900)

Comment: @AndréC Good point.  I'll vote to close that one as well.

Comment: @HenriMenke I still don't understand since almost all the questions that are asked here have an answer in reading the package manual and are therefore all off-site resources.

Comment: @AndréC It seems like as features-wise, only animations library is significant. Other features are minor. The rest is all fixes..

Comment: @berkus There is also the 3d library which is now documented.

Comment: @AndréC Agreed. The documentation for 3D library is added. Yet, the library was apparently already there...

Comment: I like this question. The question [What are the new features in TikZ/pgf 3.0?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153392) was up-voted almost 100 times and has been seen around 5k times. I think that this kind of questions has its place here (more than 90% of the questions : please draw it for me).

Comment: @HenriMenke We can turn the question into "what is missing in TikZ version 3.1?" And we can answer: "A complete and synthetic list of all the changes since the previous version!". ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I make this answer a Wiki in order to allow those who are aware of the new features of version 3.1 to make them public.

- ### A new `pic` type `right angle`

is added. *(page 561)*

> Pic type `right angle=<A>--<B>--<C>`.
>
> This pic adds a drawing of a right
> angle to the current path. It works in the same way as angle pic.

[image: pic-right-angle]

```
\tikz
  \draw (1,0,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0,0) coordinate (B) -- (0,0,1) coordinate (C)
    (B) -- (0,1,0) coordinate (D)
    pic [fill=gray,angle radius=4mm] {right angle = A--B--C}
    pic [draw,red,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=$\cdot$]
    {right angle = A--B--D};
```

- ### Unfortunately "The Data Visualization Backend"

which was not documented in version 3.0.1a is still not documented. *(page 944)*

- ### The `3d` library

that was available is now documented *(page 557)*.

- ### In `grid`

if the `xstep` or `ystep` is 0 or negative the corresponding lines are not drawn (p.157 of the documentation).

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid [xstep=.5,ystep=.75] (3,2);
  \draw[thick,red] (0,0) grid [ystep=0] (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- ### SVG Animations;

compile with `latex` and `dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1`

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click }
      :rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click }
      [fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
      {Click me!};

\end{document}
```

Static SVG and animated SVG *without* user interaction (e. g. activation on click) are embedded into HTML with the `<img>` tag, e. g.:

```
<img src="https://url/of/some.svg" width="200"/>
```

The `<img>` tag also works on this site (TeX.SX). Unfortunately, Imgur does not allow SVG file upload, but file URLs to third-party sites can be used.

Animated SVG *with* user interaction and scripted SVG (as those produced with pkg `animate`) must be embedded into HTML using the `<object>` tag:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://url/of/some.svg" width="200">
  <!-- optional (increases loading time): fallback & search engine indexing -->
  <img src="https://url/of/some.svg" />
</object>
```

Unfortunately, Blog sites and StackExchange do not accept the `<object>` tag, mainly for security reasons. As a workaround, an `<img>` tag can be used as text of a link that redirects the browser to the file URL of the SVG on click. This was done for the example above. In **Markdown** syntax:

```
[<img src="https://url/of/some.svg" width="200"/>](https://url/of/some.svg)
```

- ### Some basic tools for perspective drawing

with one, two, or three vanishing points have been added in the `perspective` library. Documentation is on page 726 (section 63) of the manual.

One of the examples from the manual can be drawn with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    isometric view,
    perspective={
      p = {(12,0,0)},
      q = {(0,12,0)},
      r = {(0,0,-12)}}]
      
    \fill[gray!80!white] (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=3,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=3,y=3,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=3,y=0,z=3) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray] (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
      -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=3,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=3,z=0) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray!50!white] (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
      -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=3,y=0,z=3)
      -- (tpp cs:x=3,y=0,z=0) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

A lot of standard Ti*k*z keys are not (yet) supported, e.g. `shift`, `xshift`, `yshift`, `rotate around x`, `rotate around y`, `rotate around z`, all the `canvas is ... plane` keys from the `3d` library, and there are bound to be more.

Answer (score 13):

Well according to the [Announcement text](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.640.1546781639.5014.ctan-ann@ctan.org) it's

> Re­lease 3.1 in­tro­duces the new an­i­ma­tions li­brary for HTML/SVG out­put and comes with tons of bug­fixes.

There's also the [full changelog](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/ChangeLog). (I borrowed this link from Henri Menke's comment)

Comment: Hopefully, this will generate a lot of SVG and animation-related questions :-)) !

Comment: @AlexG Hopefully these SVG and animated-related questions will generate lot of your interesting answers -- I'm looking forward to reading them :)

Comment: I must immediatly update!

Answer (score 2):

#### Patterns

- In 3.1.4, a new library `patterns.meta` is documented. It provides mechanisms to define new patterns. Macros `\pgfdeclarepattern` and `\tikzdeclarepattern` are documented, as well as their options, accompanied by usage examples.
- In 3.1.5, four new general and configurable patterns are added to library `patterns.meta`. They are `Lines`, `Hatch` (grids), `Dots`, and `Stars` and can be used as replacements for the ones provided by the `patterns` library.
  [image]

#### `pgfmanual.pdf` in recent versions

From [release notes](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases) of `pgf`:

- [3.1.5b](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.5b/pgfmanual.pdf),
  [3.1.5a](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.5a/pgfmanual.pdf),
  [3.1.5](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.5/pgfmanual.pdf)
- [3.1.4b](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.4b/pgfmanual.pdf),
  [3.1.4a](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.4a/pgfmanual.pdf),
  [3.1.4](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.4/pgfmanual.pdf)
- [3.1.3](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/download/3.1.3/pgfmanual.pdf)

---

The specific page and sectioning numbers per feature in `pgfmanual` changes from version to version, hence general descriptions are used.

- To read the doc for specific library or option, users can search for key words (like `patterns.meta`) in Part *References and Index* of `pgfmanual`, then jump to its documentation by clicking corresponding index entry.
- For common (option) names like `scale`, users will need to distinguish between multiple index entries.

Drawing codes behind the example image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {Lines, Hatch, Dots, Stars} {
  \tikz \path[pattern={\i}] (0, 0) rectangle node[above=1cm] {\i} (2, 2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=45]}] 
    (0, 0) rectangle node[above=1cm] {Lines} +(2, 2);

  \draw[pattern={Hatch[distance=5pt]}, pattern color=orange] 
    (2.2, 0) rectangle node[above=1cm] {Hatch} +(2, 2);

  \draw[pattern={Dots[radius=.5pt, angle=60]}] 
    (4.4, 0) rectangle node[above=1cm] {Dots} +(2, 2);

  \draw[pattern={Stars[points=5, distance=.5cm, xshift=-.15cm, angle=36]}, pattern color=blue] 
    (6.6, 0) rectangle node[above=1cm] {Stars} +(2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```