# How do we compile and visualize the animations of TikZ 3.1?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I copied and pasted the example from page 221 of manual 3.1 and tried to compile it with Texmaker.

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{animations} 

\begin{document} 

\tikz 
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click } 
:rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click } 
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle] 
{Click me!}; 

\end{document}
```

The `.pdf` file result produced does is this one:

[image: click]

The result given as an example on the manual is this one:

[image: example-manual]

I opened the `.pdf` file produced on Chrome, Opera and Firefox, I don't have any animation.

1. How should I compile the animations of TikZ 3.1?

   - on the command line
   - with Texmaker
   - with TeXstudio
2. And how do we open these files?

   - Is it possible to view them with a PDF reader?
   - Is it necessary to use a web browser?

Comment: You can't use the `dvisvgm` driver when compiling to PDF.  I'm quite surprised that you even get a usable PDF out of that.  Also you have to add `\tikzset{make snapshot if necessary}`, to force a snapshot for the PDF.

Comment: @HenriMenke : Because the drawing specials in the DVI are still PostScript. `dvisvgm` is linked against Ghostscript's `libgs.so` library.

Comment: @AlexG OP is not using `dvisvgm` but compiling to PDF.  So you end up with `dvisvgm` specials in the PDF file which is likely to corrupt the file.

Comment: @HenriMenke One can even embed EPS files with `\includegraphics` without any driver option. `dvisvgm` delegates `PSFile` special to `libgs`.

Comment: `dvisvgm` specials are mostly animation-related and simply ignored during conversion to PDF.

Comment: @HenriMenke The code I gave as an example was given to me by AlexG and I am unable to answer you on this subject. As for `\tikzset{make snapshot if necessary}` I don't understand what this is about. Perhaps you could explain your point of view in a response?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Animations works only with the SVG format. So you should compile your example at first with latex (not pdflatex). Then you should run `dvisvgm file` which will show something like this in a command line

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\tests>dvisvgm test-utf8
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  graphic size: 66.670012pt x 51.11758pt (23.431829mm x 17.965775mm)
  output written to test-utf8.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 1.64 seconds
```

You will then find a .svg-file in your folder which you can open in a browser or some other application that understand svg.

You can't
 see the animations in pdf, but you can take snapshots:

1. remove the dvisvgm option
2. then run this with pdflatex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}
\foreach \t in {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2}
{
\tikz[make snapshot of=\t]
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click }
:rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click }
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
{Click me!};}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `dvisvgm` command available on MikTeX? I don't see it on texmaker....

Comment: yes dvisvgm is in miktex too. I don't use texmaker and have no idea how to add menu entries or tools to it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer +1 Worked for me. However resulting svg file worked on Google Chrome and Firefox, not MS Edge.

Comment: @berkus I don't think so, it is a quite standard pdf. But you must compile the second example, the one without the dvisvgm option.

Comment: @AndréC sorry, typo. I meant "you can't see ...".

Comment: I am forced to compile your example with `dvisvgm` to see the snapshots in svg format. I don't get any pdf . is that normal?

Comment: The snapshots are for a pdf. Don't mix up the two methods.

Comment: Thank you, I had confused the two methods. I compiled with LaTeX, that's why. When compiling with pdfLaTeX, I see the screenshots.

Comment: @berkus Soon, MS Edge will use the same rendering engine ("Blink") as Chrome. Everything's gonna be alright then ;-).

Answer (score 25):

There are some `dvisvgm` command line options that are not mentioned in the TikZ manual, but which should generally be used.

---

## Font format: `--font-format=woff2`

LaTeX input (compile with `latex` or `dvilualatex`):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 2x dx = 1
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Compile with:

```
latex texsx-469409-a
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 texsx-469409-a
```

The default font format that `dvisvgm` embeds in the SVG output is **not** correctly interpreted by most WEB browsers. Instead, browsers use some replacement font, e. g. **Times**. Also, mathematical symbols may be incorrectly displayed:

[image]

Therefore, **always** add option `--font-format=woff2`!!! The default font format may change in future `dvisvgm` versions.

[image]

---

## Improved bounding box calculation: `--exact`

SVG-1.1, the current standard, is a single-page document format, primarily intended  for creating vector graphics to be embedded in the HTML code of Web pages. Therefore, `dvisvgm` tries to calculate the tight Bounding Box around the content of the page, similar to what the `standalone` class is made for. One could also use the `article` class together with `\pagestyle{empty}` to achieve the same result without using `standalone`; `dvisvgm` tries to crop the page around the visibile content.

In case of pure-text documents, without using graphical objects that push the page borders outwards, the resulting bounding box of the output is determined by the glyph boxes from the `tfm` files of the used font. However, these tend to be smaller than the glyphs themselves. This may lead to cropped output where parts of the glyphs are invisible because they are outside of the document edges.

`dvisvgm` provides option **`--exact`** to calculate the document's bounding box in such a way that glyph outlines fall entirely within the final bounding box.

Alternatively, the `border` option of the `standalone` document class can be set with a non-negative length value in order to add space around the content. This requires `dvisvgm` to be called with option `--bbox=papersize`. [Comment by @Martin]

---

## Responsive SVG: `--zoom=-1`

Option `--zoom=-1` produces "responsive SVG" that automatically scale to fill the available space. Such SVG don't have a fixed size. This is important for SVG to be embedded into a web page using HTML containers, such as `<object>` or `<img>`.

LaTeX input (compile with `latex` or `dvilualatex`):

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="0", 5s="1" }
:rotate = { 6s="0", 10s="360", repeats, restart=false}
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
{Hello!};

\end{document}
```

Compile with:

```
latex texsx-469409
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 texsx-469409
```

HTML code for embedding:

```
<img src="https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-469409.svg" width="200"/>
```

[image]

---

```
<img src="https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-469409.svg" width="400"/>
```

[image]

---

```
<img src="https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-469409.svg"/>
```

[image]

Comment: The borders set with the `border` option of `standalone` can be applied to the SVG by calling dvisvgm with option `--bbox=papersize`. It tells the program to evaluate the `papersize` specials present in the DVI file rather than computing a tight bounding box (which is the default).

Comment: @Martin  I didn't try the obvious, but `--bbox=dvi` which didn't have the desired effect. Thank you for your comment! I edited the answer accordingly. (`papersize` isn't mentioned in the man page, version 2.3.5.)

Comment: @God No, :(. I linked them from my GitLab page. I used the the allowed `<img>` tag. It does not permit script driven animations, but the SMIL-type animations, that can be created with the new TikZ release.

Comment: @God Maybe, but my files are innocent ;)

Comment: @God The popular Blog sites only permit the <img> tag to embed linked graphics. This tag ignores scripts. `animate`-generated, JS-driven animations only work if they are embedded with the `<object>` tag. This one is usually not available on Blog sites. (For the reasons you mentioned.)

Comment: Which ones do you mean? The ones in the answer above are **not** `animate` generated. They are SMIL-type animations *without* scripting and thus play in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for updating your answer. `--bbox=papersize` is available since version 1.16. I also updated the man page back then. So there should be some info about `papersize` specials in it. Perhaps you still have man page belonging to an older dvisvgm? The corresponding version number is mentioned at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @martin : The one in my (vanilla) TeXLive-18 installation, I guess. The man-pages says "Copyright © 2005-2016" at the bottom.

Comment: @AlexG Ok, that's a pretty old one. Isn't there a version number and a date given at the very bottom? Obviously, TL doesn't provide the documentation matching the version of dvisvgm. You can get the latest one [here](https://dvisvgm.de/Manpage).

Comment: @martin : Thanks for the link! It also documents the font format option.

Comment: When I click on the images I see on your answer, the animations do not work. However, it seems that you have embeded them from your personal web site and not from tex.stackexchange. Is that normal?

Comment: They should work without click. Do you use MS Edge, par hasard? According to a comment to Ulrike's answer above, Edge does not display animated SVG.  Try Chrome instead as Web browser. And yes, I embedded them from my web site, because Imgur does not accept SVG for upload.

Comment: @AlexG Okay, you're right, I'm changing browsers. But going from Microsoft to Google is always the GAFA....

Comment: BTW, MS recently announced that they will give up their own rendering engine in Edge in favour of "Blink", which is Google's open-source rendering engine used in their Chrome browser. It is very fast, btw. So, things will improve. This will happen this year.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add on this wiki the example from page 221 of manual 3.1? [What's new in the latest version 3.1 of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469797/138900)

Comment: When I click on an animation, I am redirected to your website where the image is displayed, is that normal?

Comment: @AndréC Yes, in the last edit I turned the `<img>` tag into a link to the svg location.

Comment: @AndréC I did the same in the example added to your wiki answer. The `<img>` tag forbids any user interaction (e. g. start-on-click) with an SVG, but the added example requires just this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88218/discussion-between-andrec-and-alexg).

Comment: +1: Simply great. Very cool stuff.

Answer (score 11):

## Configuring Texstudio for `dvisvgm`

#### Magic comments

For texstudio a quick way to compile a svg animation are magic comments, i.e. the first line in the following file

```
% !TeX TS-program = latex % | latex % | dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 %.dvi
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click }
:rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click }
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
{Click me!};

\end{document}
```

This will run latex two times and afterwards convert it animated svg

#### Create a custom user command

Another approach is to create a custom user command. In the texstudio `preferences->build` add the line

```
 latex % | latex % | dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 %.dvi
```

under "user commands":

[image]

Then one can find this open in the menu bar `Tools->user->svg` (or whatever name you chose in the previous step)

[image]

*(In case dvisvgm is not in your path variable, replace `dvisvgm` in the above commands with the full path to its installation location)*

---

## Arara rule for `dvisvgm`

With the following rule for the cool automation tool `arara`

```
!config
identifier: dvisvgm
name: DVISVGM
commands:
- name: The dvisvgm program
  command: >
    @{
        base = getBasename(file).concat('.dvi');
        return getCommand('dvisvgm', base, options);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

the following document will produce an animated svg if compiled with arara

```
% arara: latex
% arara: latex
% arara: dvisvgm : {options: ['exact', 'font-format=woff', 'zoom=-1']}
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click }
:rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click }
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
{Click me!};

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does TeXmaker offer the same possibilities as TexStudio?

Comment: @AndréC I think that texmaker does not support magic comments -- I don't know if one can defines user commands (I'd always prefer texstudio over texmaker, it offers much more options)

Comment: Is it possible to add to the compilation command line "Open with Opera"? "Open with Chrome"? "Open with the default web browser"? etc.

Comment: @AndréC Yes, for example `% !TeX TS-program = latex % | latex % | dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 %.dvi | firefox %.svg` works for me

Comment: And without naming the browser so that the system chooses the default browser itself, is that possible?

Comment: @AndréC This depends on your operating system. On mac I can do `open %.svg` to open the file with the default program associated with the file type `.svg` (which is not necessarily a browser, depending how you configured your system)

Comment: As of version 4.0.6 of `arara`, the `dvisvgm` is part of the official rule pack. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

Incredible! Work even in PDF with the `animate` package of Alexander Grahn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{animate}
\newcommand{\myAnim}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[make snapshot of=#1]
\draw (1,.5) circle [radius=1mm];
\node :shift = {
along = {(0,0) circle[radius=5mm]} upright,
0s="0", 2s="1", begin on=click }
at (1,.5) [fill = blue, opacity=.5, circle] {Click};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{5}{nSec=0+0.5}{
\myAnim{\nSec}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I like your idea to build a wrapper around TikZ's SMIL-type animations that allows us to output frame-based animations with pkg `animate`.

Comment: But this only works with linear animations, not branching ones, where objects are animated individually and interacted with by user action.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks, I don't know very well the `animate` package, certainly not well as you, I think. I make this try because the `\multiframe` command look very similar at the `\foreach` command suggested in the pgfmanual for get snapshots of the animation at a give time.