# Phantom nodes for TikZ animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, svg, dvisvgm

I am writing an animation in TikZ, where I often have one node appearing in different contexts and want to animate the path it takes from one setting to the other, for now I am preparing the settings using invisible (`opacity=0`) nodes to calculate the coordinates and anchors to then create a visible node that gets animated. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,transform shape]
    \node[circle, draw, ultra thick, fill=blue!20] (Go) at (0,-2) {Go!};

    \begin{scope}[
            every node/.style={opacity=0.2, draw},
            baseline,
            node distance=0
        ]
        \node (start-M) at (0,0) {Minimal};
        \node (start-E) [base right=of start-M] {example};
        \node (end-M) at (0,-1) {Minimal};
        \node (end-W) [base right=of end-M] {working};
        \node (end-E) [base right=of end-W] {example};
    \end{scope}

    \node (M) :position={0s="{(start-M.center)}" base, 1s="{(end-M.center)}", freeze, begin on ={click, of=Go}} {Minimal};
    \node (W) at (end-W) :opacity={0s="0" base, 1s="1", freeze, begin on={click, of=Go}} {working};
    \node (E) :position={0s="{(start-E.center)}" base, 1s="{(end-E.center)}", freeze, begin on={click, of=Go}} {example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I set `opacity=0.2` instead of `0` so you can see the nodes. See [the resulting SVG file](https://svgur.com/i/FGs.svg) (click on the go button).

I'm wondering, is it possible to have the nodes of the invisible scope not appear in the SVG file at all? I only need them to calculate positions and afterwards use these positions to draw the visisble nodes.

Comment: Why not `opacity=0` instead of `opacity=0.2`?

Comment: So you can see the nodes, as I said. Changing the opacity to `0` still results in the nodes appearing in the SVG source.

Comment: BTW, **always** add `dvisvgm` option `--font-format=woff`. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469440 .

Comment: @AlexG Thanks, I usually do that and fixed it for this MWE now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I did not think it would compile, but to my surprise it did.

Just wrap the entire `scope` used for calculating start and end coordinates of the animation paths in a `\phantom{...}` or an unused `lrbox`. This code does not produce any trace in the resulting SVG, yet fulfills its purpose of defining the needed coordinates.

[image]

Compile to SVG with `latex` (2x) and `dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1` on the intermediate DVI:

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
    \node[circle, draw, ultra thick, fill=blue!20] (Go) at (0,-2) {Go!};

    \begin{lrbox}{0}
    \begin{scope}[
            every node/.style={opacity=0.2, draw},
            baseline,
            node distance=0
        ]
        \node (start-M) at (0,0) {Minimal};
        \node (start-E) [base right=of start-M] {example};
        \node (end-M) at (0,-1) {Minimal};
        \node (end-W) [base right=of end-M] {working};
        \node (end-E) [base right=of end-W] {example};
    \end{scope}
    \end{lrbox}

    \node (M) :position={0s="{(start-M.center)}" base, 1s="{(end-M.center)}", freeze, begin on ={click, of=Go}} {Minimal};
    \node (W) at (end-W) :opacity={0s="0" base, 1s="1", freeze, begin on={click, of=Go}} {working};
    \node (E) :position={0s="{(start-E.center)}" base, 1s="{(end-E.center)}", freeze, begin on={click, of=Go}} {example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to automically add `\phantom{...}` to all the nodes within the scope?

Comment: While this does remove the `<text>` tags from the SVG file, each node still comes with a `<g transform="...">` containing a bunch of nested tags ending in an empty `<g stroke="none"/>`.

Comment: @Christoph The auxiliary code for coordinate calculation can be put in an `lrbox`. It does not produce the redundant SVG code. See edit.