# Glyph- (not stroke-) based SVG clipped at baseline

Tags: xetex, svg, dvisvgm

If I process the file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{9mm}{10mm}\selectfont
{\bfseries aceimnorsuvwxz}
\end{document}
```

using the Makefile

```
run:
    xelatex --no-pdf file
    dvisvgm file.xdv
    open file.svg
```

I get a troublesome SVG file that:

- is clipped at the baseline, due to an incorrect viewBox
- looks almost fine with Safari,

[image: safari]

but wrong with Chrome.

[image: chrome]

How can I fix both problems?

The presence of descenders lowers the clipping line, but the two issues remain.

Using:
 - dvisvgm 2.1.3
 - XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)
 - macOS 10.13.6

Comment: @Skillmon Thansk. Updated the question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @AlexG deleted my uneducated comment :)

Comment: @Calaf : For correct font rendering and clipping, dvisvgm provides `--font-format=woff` and `--exact`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://dvisvgm.de/FAQ/) of `dvisvgm` mentions the following:

> The generated SVG is most likely valid but your SVG viewer/editor
>   probably doesn’t support embedded fonts. Actually, only few SVG
>   renderers, e.g. Apache Batik and the Opera web browser evaluate
>   embedded fonts properly (also see the screenshots). You can run
>   *dvisvgm* with option `--no-fonts` to replace the fonts with path
>   elements. Most viewers should render the resulting SVG files
>   correctly. As a drawback, you get bigger files, and the information
>   about the text (characters, baselines, …) gets lost.
>
> As of version 2.0, *dvisvgm* provides the command-line option
>   `--font-format` that allows to change the format used for embedded fonts from SVG to WOFF, WOFF2 or TrueType. If you call dvisvgm with option
>   `--font-format=woff`, you should get SVG files that render correctly in almost all recent web browsers. Moreover, and in contrast to option
>   `--no-fonts`, all text properties are retained.

Indeed I could reproduce your issue with Chrome, but with WOFF the output was correct.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{9mm}{10mm}\selectfont
{\bfseries aceimnorsuvwxz}aceimnorsuvwxz
\end{document}
```

Command line:

```
dvisvgm --font-format=woff xdvconv.xdv
```

Note that I used version 2.8 of `dvisvgm`, but according to the FAQ it should work with earlier versions as well.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also add option`--exact`, as it enlarges the document BBox to completely encompass the glyphs. (By default, `dvisvgm`'s automatic BBox calculation is based on glyph box dimensions which often tend to be smaller than the glyphs themselves.) This makes the `border` document option redundant.

Comment: @Calaf With `--font-formt=woff`, text is searchable and copiable.