# pdf to svg conversion puzzle

Tags: xetex, pdftex, svg

I am looking for a reliable way to convert a pdf from a latex file to SVG for display in a browser

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{rrrrrrrrrr}
     \begin{block}{rrrr(cccc|c)!{\quad}l}
          &  &  &  & 1 & 2                   & 2  & 1  & 8  & the pivot is in row 2, col 2\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{$\boxed{1}$}}}       & -1 & 0  & 0  & It will be multiplied by\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{-2}}} & 1  & -2 & -5 & entries in column 1 of $E$ \\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{\ 1}}} & -1 & 1  & 2  & \\
     \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

1. I had used `\documentclass{standalone}` which did not work
   I ended up with removing the pagenumber and using the following ugly shellscript

```
!/bin/sh
latexmk -pdflatex $1.tex && \
latexmk -pdflatex -c $1.tex && \
pdf2svg $1.pdf /tmp/temp_$1.svg && \
inkscape -D --without-gui --file=/tmp/temp_$1.svg --export-plain-svg $1.svg
```

Questions

- Is there a simpler way to create the svg so that the image is cropped to the actual extent?
  (the -D option for inkscape)
- Is there a simpler way to create the pdf so that it only displays that image, rather than the whole page?
- The parentheses enclosing the matrix get messed up with most of my attempts.
  What would I need to do to ensure that parens will be correctly rendered
- can whatever solution use xelatex rather than pdflatex?

Comment: What problem did you get when you used `standalone`? I’ve sometimes wrapped the contents in display math or a minipage to get that to work.

Comment: pdf2svg is obsolete, afaik. Use `dvisvgm` instead. It ships with TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't compile: `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \boxed`

Comment: Oops! I also had  `\usepackage{nicematrix}` in the original preamble

Comment: dvisgm does not handle the parentheses correctly :(

Comment: It does, if you use the right options ;-): `dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 --exact your-example.dvi`

Comment: Yay! that did work indeed! Thank you

Comment: nah, I still have examples where dvisgm messes up the parens, while pdf2svg does not!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if you just want to convert a pdf to an svg, why not just use Inkscape?

Comment: @ea42-gh ```amsmath``` package is missing... then you might have got the ```Undefined control sequence``` error, as I had.

Comment: @AlexG why is `pdf2svg` obsolete? IMHO, `dvi` output is much more obsolete, so usage of `dvisgm` makes no sense.

Comment: That's bean-counting. Besides, `dvisvgm` is just a name. It also converts PDF.

Comment: For reference, `-P` flag can be used to make dvisvgm output PDF. That having said, unfortunately none of `dvisvgm`, `inkscape`, `pdf2svg` preserves the hyperlinks in my testing. StackOverflow question on that: [Inkscape pdf to svg export - retain hyperlinks - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750771/inkscape-pdf-to-svg-export-retain-hyperlinks)

Comment: Related: [conversion - How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pdf2svg`, which is unmaintained, I would use `dvisvgm` which is part of TeXLive/MiKTeX and actively maintained.

The combination of `--exact` and `--zoom=-1` trims the output to the visible content and makes it responsive which facilitates embedding into HTML (options explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469440)).

```bash
latex input
dvisvgm --exact --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 input
```

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{rrrrrrrrrr}
     \begin{block}{rrrr(cccc|c)!{\quad}l}
          &  &  &  & 1 & 2                   & 2  & 1  & 8  & the pivot is in row 2, col 2\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{$\boxed{1}$}}}       & -1 & 0  & 0  & It will be multiplied by\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{-2}}} & 1  & -2 & -5 & entries in column 1 of $E$ \\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{\ 1}}} & -1 & 1  & 2  & \\
     \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the missing `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{rrrrrrrrrr}
     \begin{block}{rrrr(cccc|c)!{\quad}l}
          &  &  &  & 1 & 2                   & 2  & 1  & 8  & the pivot is in row 2, col 2\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{$\boxed{1}$}}}       & -1 & 0  & 0  & It will be multiplied by\\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{-2}}} & 1  & -2 & -5 & entries in column 1 of $E$ \\
          &  &  &  & 0 & {\colorbox{yellow}{\color{darkred}{\ 1}}} & -1 & 1  & 2  & \\
     \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

Then compile and convert from PDF to SVG as you suggested.

```
#!/bin/bash
latexmk -pdflatex $1.tex && \
latexmk -pdflatex -c $1.tex && \
pdf2svg $1.pdf $1.svg
```

Answer (score -1):

Each of the toolchains fails under diverse circumstances, depending on
the latex engine, the document class and the packages used.

I am adding a current (python/linux) version of a function building
the toolchain `tex_program -> svg_converter -> svg_crop` as a a list of command parameters that can be used in a python call to run a subprocess.
Not the `nexec` parameter is the number of times `tex_program` will be invoked.
It is not applicable for all combinations...

```python
def build_commands( tex_program=["pdflatex"], svg_converter=[["pdf2svg"],".pdf"], use_xetex=False, use_dvi=False, crop=False, nexec=1):
    if isinstance( tex_program, (list,)) is False:
        tex_program = [tex_program]

    if tex_program[0]  == "pdflatex":
        if use_xetex is True:
            if use_dvi is True:
                if nexec > 1:
                    _tex_program = ["xelatex", "--no-pdf", "-etex" ]
                    _svg_converter = [["dvisvgm", "--font-format=woff2", "--exact"], ".xdv"]
                else:
                    _tex_program = ["latexmk", "-xelatex", "-etex" ]
                    _svg_converter = [["dvisvgm", "--font-format=woff2", "--exact"], ".xdv"]
            else:
                if nexec > 1:
                    _tex_program = ["xelatex", "-etex" ]
                    _svg_converter = [["pdf2svg"], ".pdf"]
                else:
                    _tex_program = ["latexmk", "-xelatex", "-etex" ]
                    _svg_converter = [["pdf2svg"], ".pdf"]
        else:
            if use_dvi is True:
                _tex_program = ["latexmk", "-etex", "-dvi" ]
                _svg_converter = [["dvisvgm", "--font-format=woff2", "--exact"], ".dvi"]
            else:
                _tex_program = ["latexmk", "-etex", "-pdf" ]
                _svg_converter = [["pdf2svg"], ".pdf"]
    else:
       _tex_program = tex_program
       _svg_converter = svg_converter
    if crop:
        _svg_crop = (["inkscape", "-D", "--without-gui", "--file"], ["--export-plain-svg"])
    else:
        _svg_crop = None

    return _tex_program, _svg_converter,_svg_crop
```

To invoke the programs, I use code along the lines of the following

```python
tex_program.append( tex_path )
for _ in range(nexec-1):
    run_subprocess(tex_program, cwd=working_dir)
    check_output(tex_program, cwd=working_dir)

    svg_program = svg_converter[0] + [pdf_path, svg_path]
    check_output(svg_program, cwd=working_dir)

    if svg_crop is not None:
        crop_program = svg_crop[0] + [svg_path] + svg_crop[1] + [svg_path]
        check_output( crop_program, cwd=working_dir)
```