# Tikz: Your graphic driver pgfsys-pdftex.def does not support animations

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have a problem with animations in Tikz.
I get the following error message: Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-pdftex.def does not support animations.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\tikz \draw :xshift = {0s = "0cm", 30s = "-3cm", repeats} (0,0) circle (5mm);

\end{document}
```

So if anyone can help me?

Here is the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.1.16)  20 JAN 2023 09:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./essai2_tikz.tex
(essai2_tikz.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-12-17>
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.
sty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.st
y
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil
-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil
-common-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil
-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.
code.tex
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.
sty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.
sty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks20
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks21

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
filtered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks22
))
\pgf@x=\dimen145
\pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@xa=\dimen147
\pgf@ya=\dimen148
\pgf@xb=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150
\pgf@xc=\dimen151
\pgf@yc=\dimen152
\pgf@xd=\dimen153
\pgf@yd=\dimen154
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count193
\c@pgf@countb=\count194
\c@pgf@countc=\count195
\c@pgf@countd=\count196
\t@pgf@toka=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks25
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count197

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.c
fg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
ssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count198
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count199
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
sprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
e.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code
.tex
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.
code.tex
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.
code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparse
r.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen155
\pgfmath@count=\count266
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks28
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.code.tex
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count267
))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.
tex)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen156
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen157
\pgf@picminy=\dimen158
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen159
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen163
\pgf@xx=\dimen164
\pgf@xy=\dimen165
\pgf@yx=\dimen166
\pgf@yy=\dimen167
\pgf@zx=\dimen168
\pgf@zy=\dimen169
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen170
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen171
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen172
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen173
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
escopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count268
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
egraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen174
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
etransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen177
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
equick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
earrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen178
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen179
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count269
\pgf@shadingcount=\count270
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
elayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
etransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
erdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
shapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
plot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfco
mp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen180
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen181
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfco
mp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.st
y
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code
.tex))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.
code.tex
Package: pgffor 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code
.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen182
\pgffor@skip=\dimen183
\pgffor@stack=\toks29
\pgffor@toks=\toks30
))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibr
aryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count271
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen184
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen185
\tikz@lasty=\dimen186
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen190
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen191
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen192
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count272
\tikznumberofchildren=\count273
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count274
\tikz@fig@count=\count275

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
matrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count276
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count277
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count278
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count279

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibraryanimations.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryanimations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
animations.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleanimations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
sanimations.code.tex
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
decorations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen193
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen194
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen195
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen196
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen197
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count280
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen198
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen199
)
\pgfsysanim@snap@count=\count281
\pgfsysanim@lasttime=\dimen256
)
\pgf@anim@dim=\dimen257
)
\tikz@anim@once@count=\count282
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-10-26 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count283
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
)
No file essai2_tikz.aux.
\openout1 = `essai2_tikz.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count284
\scratchdimen=\dimen258
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count285
\nofMParguments=\count286
\everyMPshowfont=\toks31
\MPscratchCnt=\count287
\MPscratchDim=\dimen259
\MPnumerator=\count288
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count289
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks32
)
(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))

Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-pdftex.def does not support ani
mations. This warning is given only once on input line 10.

[1

{C:/Users/didie/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(essai2_tikz.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13364 strings out of 476406
 293144 string characters out of 2789567
 1849787 words of memory out of 3000000
 33537 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 513050 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 100i,5n,104p,444b,549s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
 <C:\Users\didie\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknapp
en/ec/dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on essai2_tikz.pdf (1 page, 1939 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The `animations` library for TikZ/pgf works only for SVG output, that is, via `[dvilua]latex` + `dvisvgm`. If you are interested in SVG output with this type of animations, read this question and answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469409

Comment: Thank you @AlexG, I'll check that

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) in section 26 (page 380) about the `animations` tikzlibrary.

Quote from section 26.1.1 on page 381:

> To make a long story short: TikZ animations currently work only with SVG output (and use the SMIL "flavor" of describing animations). In future, it may well happen that other "flavor" [sic] of describing animations
> will be added, but it is very unlikely that PDF will ever support animations in a useful way.

And section 26.1.2 *Limitations of the Animation System*:

> There are a certain limitations of the animation system that you should keep in mind when considering how
> and when to use it:
>
> 1. As pointed out earlier, animations require a specific output format (currently only SVG is supported).

Since you tried to use PDF output the warning is generated.

Comment: Thank you Marijin for your answer. But what should I do for it to work? I tried with Latex-dvips-dvi2pdf but that doesn't work either. Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support animations. I found a pdf on the web with a animation created by tikz and it works fine

Comment: Your code uses `\usetikzlibrary{animations}`. The quote from the manual above is about that library, it explains that you can only use that library for SVG output. This output has to be produced _directly_, so not through compilation to pdf and conversion afterwards (see page 121 of the library, section 10.2.4 Producing SVG Output). If you have seen a pdf that contains a TikZ animation then it is made in a different way, for example with the `animate` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/animate) or by including a video file.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

While the `animations` library is intended for creating animated SVG in the first place, it can still be used for other output formats, such as PDF.

The key `/tikz/make snapshot of=<time>` can be used to convert this kind of animation into a PDF animation. Typeset with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop]{25}
\multiframe{\inteval{30*25+1}}{rTime=0+\fpeval{1/25}}{ % total number of frames = duration * frames per second + 1
  \tikz [make snapshot of = \rTime] {
    \useasboundingbox (-3,0) circle (5mm) (0,0) circle (5mm);
    \draw :xshift = {0s = "0cm", 30s = "-3cm", repeats} (0,0) circle (5mm);
  }
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Another example taken from the Ti*k*Z documentation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop, controls, width=2in]{25}
\multiframe{\inteval{10*25+1}}{rTime=0+\fpeval{1/25}}{
  \tikz [make snapshot of = \rTime]
    \node :fill opacity = { 0s="0", 5s="1" }
    :rotate = { 6s="0", 10s="360", repeats, restart=false}
    [fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle]
    {Hello!};
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```