# How to get svg output, using smil

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make animations with a shorter compilation time, using the TikZ animations library.

According to the PGF/TikZ manual, "TikZ animations currently work only with svg output (and use the smil “flavor” of describing animations)."

I don't know how to compile documents in the svg format, let alone how to use smil. I tried using dvisvgm and command line prompts, but don't know how to get it to work.

I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through (like I've never done this before) how to get all this set up.

If possible, a MWE would be very helpful to see.

Thank you

MWE: (compiled using `pdflatex -shell-escape animation.tex`
)

```
\documentclass[preview,convert={outfile=animation.svg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \begin{scope}[animate={1s}]
    \draw (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \pgftransformxshift{1cm} % move the rectangle to the right
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469409