TikZ Objects are misplaced when converting to animated svg via dvisvgm
The goal is to have an animation that displays a text one character at at time. The following MWE produces only somewhat the desired result:
\documentclass[dvisvgm, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
    function createNodeText(frame, position, text, charSpeed)  
        textLen = string.len(text) 
        textTmp = "|"
        textTmpLen = 0
        for i=1, textLen do
            if frame+1 >= i*charSpeed then
                textTmpLen = textTmpLen + 1
            end
        end
        if frame >= textLen * charSpeed then
            textTmp = ""
        end 
        tex.sprint("\\node[anchor = west,text=white, font=\\Huge, minimum width=5cm] at " .. position .. "{\\phantom{|}" .. string.sub(text, 1, textTmpLen) .. textTmp .."};")
    end
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}%
    \begin{frame}%
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{60}%
            \multiframe{360}{rt=0+1}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
                    \useasboundingbox (-8,-4.5)rectangle++(16,9);%
                    \fill[green](-2,-2)rectangle++(4,4);
                    \directlua{createNodeText(\rt,"(0,0)","Hello World!", 10)}%
                \end{tikzpicture}%
            }%
        \end{animateinline}%
    \end{frame} %
\end{document}

After compilation with dvilualatex mwe and conversion to svg via
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 --output=./%f_%0p.svg mwe.dvi

are neither the text positioned correctly nor the beamer background is aligned properly:

Additionally, when adding other objects (in this case \fill[green](-2,-2)rectangle++(4,4);) to the drawing, the relative position between the objects is also incorrect:

Desired output would be:

Questions:

Is there a way to get in this case the animate package and dvisvgm to respect the positioning? As far as I understand, animate creates overlays for the animations, which do not inherit the required information. One of my failed attempts was to use the remember picture and overlay options to gain access to the page anchors via current page. However, this did not work as the animate package refusing to compile due to the "zero size" issue.
Might there be a possibility to achieve the same result with the animations TikZ library? As far as I understand, there is no way to animate the node text itself (only its color, opacity, etc.) and there is also no access to the internal time state (as far as I am aware of).

Edit 1: Suggestions from the Comments
Use dvisvgm to convert pdf to svg
Technically it is possible to convert pdf to svg with dvisvgm. However, the pdf source cannot hold all the required information to reconstruct the animation in the svg.
Adapting the above MWE to the pdf -> svg Pipeline
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
    function createNodeText(frame, position, text, charSpeed)  
        textLen = string.len(text) 
        textTmp = "|"
        textTmpLen = 0
        for i=1, textLen do
            if frame+1 >= i*charSpeed then
                textTmpLen = textTmpLen + 1
            end
        end
        if frame >= textLen * charSpeed then
            textTmp = ""
        end 
        tex.sprint("\\node[anchor = west,text=white, font=\\Huge, minimum width=5cm] at " .. position .. "{\\phantom{|}" .. string.sub(text, 1, textTmpLen) .. textTmp .."};")
    end
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}%
    \begin{frame}%
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{60}%
            \multiframe{360}{rt=0+1}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
                    \useasboundingbox (-8,-4.5)rectangle++(16,9);%
                    \fill[green](-2,-2)rectangle++(4,4);
                    \directlua{createNodeText(\rt,"(0,0)","Hello World!", 10)}%
                \end{tikzpicture}%
            }%
        \end{animateinline}%
    \end{frame} %
\end{document}

and creating the svg via lualatex mwe and
dvisvgm --pdf --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 --output=./%f_%0p.svg mwe.pdf

leads to the following result:

No text is displayed and the animation is not playing.
Use beamer animations
To quote the beamer Manual, section 14.1.2 (Animations Created by Showing Slides in Rapid Succession):

You can create an animation in a portable way by using the overlay commands of the beamer package
to create a series of slides that, when shown in rapid succession, present an animation. This is a flexible
approach, but such animations will typically be rather static since it will take some time to advance from one
slide to the next. This approach is mostly useful for animations where you want to explain each “picture”
of the animation. When you advance slides “by hand,” that is, by pressing a forward button, it typically
takes at least a second for the next slide to show.
More “lively” animations can be created by relying on a capability of the viewer program. Some programs
support showing slides only for a certain number of seconds during a presentation (for the Acrobat Reader
this works only in full-screen mode). By setting the number of seconds to zero, you can create a rapid
succession of slides.

Yes, so it technically would be possible to use beamer animations for creating "automatic" animations (MWE will follow). However, as the manual states that this is "relying on a capability of the viewer program". For my use case, I cannot guarantee that I will have the right viewer available when presenting (can be a e.g. conference laptop where I cannot control the available software), so I would rather not rely on this.
In addition, when requiring the conversion to svg, since the animation will span multiple pages in the pdf, multiple svg output files will be created by default. This is problematic if one wants to have an animation running automatically. Sure, one could write e.g. some JavaScript to fix this, but I would prefer a simple solution without requiring manual fixing afterwards. If there is a good way to compress multiple pdf pages into one svg (e.g. during conversion with dvisvgm) to create an animated svg, please let me know, because my attempts were not successful.

One could use TikZ' current page node to position the animation absolutely on the page. Unfortunately this does not work in DVI mode (needed as an intermediate for final SVG output). The current page node is only available in PDF mode. Do you absolutely need SVG?

@AlexG: Yes, as (indirectly) stated in the question I already tried the current page approach and realized it does not work in this case. And yes, I absolutely need the svg output, since the posted MWE is intended to be used for presenting at conferences with reliability of the animations being of upmost essence (and the reliability/mileage with pdf animations is at the time of writing not very good).

@AlexG The interesting thing is that if I use XeTeX and the animation TikZ library, I can use the current page approach, as XeTeX produces xdv files. However, if I try XeTeX in combination with the animate package and current page, I immediately run again into the "zero size" error.

With dvisvgm is possibile to convert pdf into svg. Besides this the beamer class has a mechanism for the creation of animations. Look at the documentation.

@vi pa While it is possible to use dvisvgm to convert PDF into svg, certain features of the animate package as well as the animation TikZ library are not available. The usage of beamer animations does not really work in case of the specific AUTOMATIC animations I am after. I added further information to the question detailing about your suggestions.

If can help try with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469611/162128

@vi pa Thank you very much for this link. This information actually solves another problem I have in certain situations (how to start TikZ animations automatically and how to interact with node attributes) :-)

After some tinkering, and the suggestion by @vi pa (especially  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469611/162128), I found a solution that kind-of works (at least for my intended use case).
Solution
Source Code
\documentclass[dvisvgm, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
    cursorPhantom = "\\phantom{|}"
    function createNodeText(frame, text, charSpeed)  
        textLen = string.len(text) 
        cursor = "|"
        textTmpLen = 0
        for i=1, textLen do
            if frame+1 >= i*charSpeed then
                textTmpLen = textTmpLen + 1
            end
        end
        if frame >= textLen * charSpeed then
            cursor = cursorPhantom
        end 
        tex.sprint(cursorPhantom .. string.sub(text, 1, textTmpLen) .. cursor)
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}%
    \begin{frame}%
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{60}%
            \multiframe{360}{rt=0+1}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
                    % REMARK: Adjustment of Bounding Box to properly fit beamer frame
                    \useasboundingbox (-\textwidth/2,-\textheight/2)rectangle++(\textwidth,\textheight);%
                    \fill[green](-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);%
    
                    % REMARK: anchor=west was problematic
                    \node[text=white, font=\Huge, minimum width=5cm] at (0,0){%
                        \directlua{createNodeText(\rt,"Hello World!", 10)}%
                    };%
                \end{tikzpicture}%
            }%
        \end{animateinline}%
    \end{frame} %
\end{document}

It turns out that I had not given \useasboundingbox the correct size, so consequently the elements would not center properly in respect to the beamer frame. Setting the bounding box to \textwidth and \textheight respetively solved this issue except for some edge cases (see Limitations below).
The misalignment of the text was caused by usage of the anchor=west attribute and could be solved by setting the node anchor to default.
Output
After compilation with dvilualatex mwe and conversion to svg via
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 --output=./%f_%0p.svg mwe.dvi

the correct result is obtained:

Limitations

Only works if the animation is the only thing on that beamer slide. Otherwise the alignment of the animation in respect to the rest of the frame will be off due to the movable TeX boxes created by the animate package. This is especially important for converting to svg, since the resulting relative placement in the converted svg is a bit finicky.
Text has to be centered and scrolling while adding the characters. This can maybe changed if one adds the remainder of the string via \phantom{<REMAINDER>} to the node text.
Usage of \scalebox and \rotatebox within the node text is not possible. One \scalebox per animation might work fine, but as soon as there are more than one, the layout in the svg output is shifted. The same happens as soon as a \rotatebox is used.


animate doesn't do overlay actions. It produces an ordinary TeX box that can be moved around like other TeX boxes, such as an image included with \includegraphics, an \mbox{...} or a single letter.

@AlexG updated the question accordingly. Thank you for clarifying that detail!

The animation widget's dimensions shouldn't be larger than its visible content. Then, for centering on the page, it is sufficient to wrap it into a plain center environment.
The letters of the animated text appear one at a time. Thus, the total number of animation frames can be limited to the number of characters contained in the text string plus a few additional frames at the end that show the complete string for a short while. The frame rate can be reduced to the frequency at which the letters appear. This saves file size and simplifies the Lua code.
Finally, the cursor was put in a zero-width mbox to prevent the text  from being re-centred when the cursor disappears after completing it. Also, the cursor is exactly centred when the animation starts.
PDF version (Firefox >= 130)
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
  function createNodeText(idx, text)
    if idx>0 then
      tex.sprint(string.sub(text, 1, idx))
    end
    if idx <= string.len(text) then
      tex.sprint("\\makebox[0pt]{|}")
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\animText{"Hello World!"}

\begin{document}
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}%
  \begin{frame}%[c]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{5}
         \multiframe{\directlua{tex.sprint(5+string.len(\animText))}}{idx=0+1}{
           \begin{tikzpicture}
             \useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
             \fill[green](-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
             \node[text=white, font=\Huge] at (0,0){\strut\directlua{createNodeText(\idx, \animText)}};
           \end{tikzpicture}
         }
      \end{animateinline}
    \end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for this clean solution! The usage of \strut for defining the height of the node makes it way more reliable than my previous example. I assume the 5+ in the \directlua{tex.sprint(5+string.len(\animText))} expression is there to create  a 5 frame (corresponding 1s) "waiting time" before the animation would restart?

Exactly ;), as stated in the second paragraph.
