# An undesirable path occurs when I intersect two paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is an undesirable path in my result.
[image]

However, if I comment out the path intersection code (the fourth line from below), the undesirable path disappears.
[image]

One of the paths involved in the intersection is a closed path (that is, `\path [name path=Part2] (BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle` in my code). I cannot figure out why an intersection involving a closed path can generate some path outside the closed path. What I want to produce is as follows.
[image]

I would appreciate your help with this situation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (3,1.5);
\coordinate (BLM) at (0.5,-2);  %below leftmost
\coordinate (BRM) at (6,-1.5);  %below rightmost
\coordinate (BM) at (3.5,-1.8); %below middle 
\coordinate (BL) at (2,-2.1);   
\coordinate (BR) at (5,-2.5);   
\draw (BR) -- (BRM) -- (A) -- (BLM) -- (BL) -- (BM) -- cycle;
\foreach \pt in {BL,BM,BR}
    \draw (A) -- (\pt);
\foreach \pt/\xshift/\yshift in {BLM/-0.5cm/-0.7cm, BL/-0.2cm/-0.72cm, BM/0.1cm/-0.66cm, BR/0.4cm/-0.8cm, BRM/0.6cm/-0.6cm}
{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
        \coordinate (\pt\i) at ($(A)+\i*(\xshift,\yshift)$);
}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (BLM\i) -- (BL\i) -- (BM\i) -- (BR\i) -- (BRM\i);
    
\path [name path=Part2] (BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,2.5}
{
    \path [overlay,name path=slashpath\x,draw] ($(BLM2)+(\x,0)-(0.35,0.2)$) -- +(50:1.5cm);
    \draw [name intersections={of=Part2 and slashpath\x},very thin] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete (`\documentclass`, `document` environment and required `tikz` libraries are all missing) and raises error even after I make it complete. Meanwhile, when `x = 0`, paths `Part2` and `slashpath0` (the left most slash line) do not intersect. What drawing effect do you want to achieve by generating intersections?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my post. Just as you say, `x=0` is redundant in this case.

Comment: Still the same error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've placed `% <----` this to highlight each change in your code.

## Update 2: Clean up of the code

When performing the `clip` operation, the search for `intersections` is useless since the `clip` does this natively. The `clip` transforms the path you called name `path=Part2` into a pochoir *(stencil)* and therefore everything that is hatched is colored inside this pochoir (clip area or stencil). So there's no need to search for `intersections` like you do.

The simplified code is now (same result):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (3,1.5);
\coordinate (BLM) at (0.5,-2);  %below leftmost
\coordinate (BRM) at (6,-1.5);  %below rightmost
\coordinate (BM) at (3.5,-1.8); %below middle 
\coordinate (BL) at (2,-2.1);   
\coordinate (BR) at (5,-2.5);   
\draw (BR) -- (BRM) -- (A) -- (BLM) -- (BL) -- (BM) -- cycle;
\foreach \pt in {BL,BM,BR}
    \draw (A) -- (\pt);
\foreach \pt/\xshift/\yshift in {BLM/-0.5cm/-0.7cm, BL/-0.2cm/-0.72cm, BM/0.1cm/-0.66cm, BR/0.4cm/-0.8cm, BRM/0.6cm/-0.6cm}
{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
        \coordinate (\pt\i) at ($(A)+\i*(\xshift,\yshift)$);
}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (BLM\i) -- (BL\i) -- (BM\i) -- (BR\i) -- (BRM\i);
    \begin{scope}% <---- add scope here
    
\path [clip%,name path=Part2 <-- add clip delete useless name path
] (BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle;%<----- add clip here
\foreach \x in {0.25,.5,...,2.5}%<----- delete 0 here
%{ <-- useless group with only one TikZ command
    \path [%name path=slashpath\x, <-- useless name path
    draw] ($(BLM2)+(\x,0)-(0.35,0.2)$) -- +(50:1.5cm);
    %\draw [name intersections={of=Part2 and slashpath\x},very thin] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2); <--- useless intersections
%}
    \end{scope}%<----- end of scope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

## Update 1: Explanations about `clip` et `scope`

What is important here is the `clip` action. `clip` makes it possible to virtually cut out the figure as one would do with scissors. Clip acts like a [pochoir *(in french)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil) (stencil in english). It is like a mask that hides everything that is not cut out. It only leaves the inner part of the clip *(pochoir)* visible. Once clipped, everything that is drawn only appears within the clip *(pochoir)*.

Everything that is drawn after the clip remains inside this pochoir. Everything else is hidden, the constructions and drawings made remain inside the pochoir.

This scope environment is useful here because it limits the cutting when you want to work on a piece of the figure, but not on the whole figure.

It delimits a part of the figure. Here, it limits the pochoir within this scope environment.

When you get out of this scope, you can draw on the complete figure again.

In the case of your figure, the scope environment is not useful because you don't build anything more after this clip.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (3,1.5);
\coordinate (BLM) at (0.5,-2);  %below leftmost
\coordinate (BRM) at (6,-1.5);  %below rightmost
\coordinate (BM) at (3.5,-1.8); %below middle 
\coordinate (BL) at (2,-2.1);   
\coordinate (BR) at (5,-2.5);   
\draw (BR) -- (BRM) -- (A) -- (BLM) -- (BL) -- (BM) -- cycle;
\foreach \pt in {BL,BM,BR}
    \draw (A) -- (\pt);
\foreach \pt/\xshift/\yshift in {BLM/-0.5cm/-0.7cm, BL/-0.2cm/-0.72cm, BM/0.1cm/-0.66cm, BR/0.4cm/-0.8cm, BRM/0.6cm/-0.6cm}
{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
        \coordinate (\pt\i) at ($(A)+\i*(\xshift,\yshift)$);
}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (BLM\i) -- (BL\i) -- (BM\i) -- (BR\i) -- (BRM\i);
    \begin{scope}% <---- add scope here
    
\path [clip,name path=Part2] (BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle;%<----- add clip here
\foreach \x in {0.25,.5,...,2.5}%<----- delete 0 here
{
    \path [overlay,name path=slashpath\x,draw] ($(BLM2)+(\x,0)-(0.35,0.2)$) -- +(50:1.5cm);
    \draw [name intersections={of=Part2 and slashpath\x},very thin] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
}
    \end{scope}%<----- end of scope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but I have no idea why I need scope here. Could you give me more clues? Thanks!

Comment: @lightweight I have added some explanations, I hope they are clear enough. If you still don't understand, just say so.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative explanation, but I still have a problem. The path `Part2` in my code (that is, `(BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle`) is closed. I cannot figure out why an intersection involving a closed path can generate some path outside the closed path.

Comment: Your code on MikTeX with the pdfLaTeX engine does not compile. It does not generate anything. It only compiles when you iterate on `{0.25,.5,...,2.5}`. What engine do you compile with? pdfLaTeX? LaTeX? Lua LaTeX ? another one ?

Comment: XeLaTeX. I wrote my above codes with other codes in a same document. When I compile, there is no error or warning (https://imgur.com/KJ2pBq0) except the weird result I described in my question. However, after your most recent comment, I test my codes pertaining to this question in a standalone document, and the compilation tells me `No shape named 'intersection-1' is known` (same for `intersection-2`). Now I guess `.`(period) of `\x` in `slashpath\x` may be the cause of problem. I replace `{0.25,.5,...,2.5}` (after `\foreach`) with `{1,2,...,10}` and `(\x,0)` with `(0.25*\x,0)`, and it works.

Comment: @lightweight I have updated my answer by simplifying the code because it is not necessary to use intersections. As I cannot reproduce the problem of the line that concerns me is ghost, I cannot explain why for you it appeared.

Answer (score 5):

To fill an area by slashing lines in `tikz`, using pattern is easier than intersections.

Here

- `tikz` library `patterns.meta` is loaded and
- `\path [name path=Part2]` is replaced with `pattern={Lines[angle=50, distance=5pt]}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (3,1.5);
  \coordinate (BLM) at (0.5,-2);  %below leftmost
  \coordinate (BRM) at (6,-1.5);  %below rightmost
  \coordinate (BM) at (3.5,-1.8); %below middle 
  \coordinate (BL) at (2,-2.1);   
  \coordinate (BR) at (5,-2.5);
  
  \draw (BR) -- (BRM) -- (A) -- (BLM) -- (BL) -- (BM) -- cycle;
  \foreach \pt in {BL,BM,BR}
      \draw (A) -- (\pt);
  \foreach \pt/\xshift/\yshift in {BLM/-0.5cm/-0.7cm, BL/-0.2cm/-0.72cm, BM/0.1cm/-0.66cm, BR/0.4cm/-0.8cm, BRM/0.6cm/-0.6cm}
  {
      \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
          \coordinate (\pt\i) at ($(A)+\i*(\xshift,\yshift)$);
  }
  
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
      \draw (BLM\i) -- (BL\i) -- (BM\i) -- (BR\i) -- (BRM\i);
  
  % draw pattern
  \path[pattern={Lines[angle=50, distance=5pt]}] 
    (BRM1) -- (BR1) -- (BM1) -- (BL1) -- (BLM1) -- (BLM2) -- (BL2) -- (BM2) -- (BR2) -- (BRM2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`tikz` library `patterns.meta` is documented in [`pgfmanual` v3.1.5b](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 63.3. You can learn docs and examples of pattern `Lines` and its options in that subsection.

PS: pattern `Lines` is newly added in `pgf/tikz` v3.1.5, see corresponding [release notes](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.5).

Comment: +1. This library was not documented in version 3.0.1a. Can you update this wiki? [What's new in the latest version 3.1 of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469007/whats-new-in-the-latest-version-3-1-of-tikz)

Comment: @AndréC Pattern `Lines` is added in 3.1.5, and I've added a note to my answer. (Package `patterns.meta` is more complex, it has been there for a long time but not documented until 3.1.4.) The linked question seems to ask for a list of new features added in 3.1. I'm not sure if 3.1.5 features are suited there.

Comment: If it is relevant, because 3.1 means exactly all versions of 3.1, it is enough to specify that it is since 3.1.5 that this exists. The idea is to make the new features public because nobody ever reads the whole documentation *(except the person who wrote it)*.

Comment: @AndréC [Release notes](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases) is not long, though fewer find it. OK I will add new patterns in `patterns.meta` to the linked question. This makes it even softer, since it asks for a list containing future changes.

Comment: You have the point of view of a great TikZ and TeX specialist. Given the number of questions asked by beginners here, the release notes are from experts talking to other experts. The popularity of TikZ makes it necessary to simply talk to beginners who are new to LaTeX, TikZ, forums etc.

Comment: "... the release notes are from experts talking to other experts." Agreed. Since the pgfmanual doesn't contain per feature version info (when added, when modified, when deprecated), there is always a need for release notes intended for moderate users.

Comment: And it is also necessary to address beginners who discover TikZ through examples showing the new features.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ @AndréC Thanks for all your help. I have encountered some problem using the library `patterns.meta` before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549352/125357. My resulting lines generated by method like `pattern={Lines[angle=50, distance=5pt]}` are not smooth. My pdf reader is Adobe.

Comment: @lightweight After some tracing, it seems when the pattern cell (the repeated unit of drawing, in this example a square containing slashed lines) contains touching and slashed drawings, caused by both rounding errors of tex and the pdf reader, the inner borders of pattern cells won't look smooth (in some combination of `distance` and `angle`).